# Is it possible to run some steps within one Junit test in parallel with failsafe library?

Tags: multithreading, maven, unit-testing, parallel-processing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I don't want to run separate tests in parallel, but I want to run steps within one test in parallel, for example if three clusters need to be created, I want them to be created parallelly. I don't fully understand maven-failsafe but I was wondering if it will help me achieve this easily or if i should use normal Java threads?

Comment: Can you give an concrete example (best would be code) and how you have configured pom.xml which junit you are using? versions etc. ?

Comment: I have a create-cluster method (could be anything else also) in a for loop which runs thrice sequentially, I'd like to make that happen parallelly instead of the loop. I am using junit 4.13.2 currently but no hard dependency on it and can change this if needed. My question is mostly about if failsafe is right for this usecase

Comment: To be honest enhance your post with much more details because I don't understand your real problem.. you wrote: `but I want to run steps within one test in parallel,` what does that mean? Using Threads? Where is the relationship to failsafe plugin... apart from that have you checked the documentation of maven-failsafe/surefire plugin https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/ about parallelization of tests?